# Using Omnipay for Pin Payments

Tags: php, omnipay

I am trying to use [Omnipay](https://github.com/adrianmacneil/omnipay) to process Pin Payment transactions and have the following code (almost exactly the same as the [example on the Pin website](https://pin.net.au/docs/languages/php), and containing my secret API Key instead of 'key'):

```
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
use Omnipay\Common\GatewayFactory;

$gateway = GatewayFactory::create('Pin');
$gateway->setApiKey('key');
$gateway->purchase([
    'email'       => 'customer@email.com',
    'description' => 'Widgets',
    'amount'      => '49.99',
    'currency'    => 'USD',
    'card_token'  => 'card_nytGw7koRg23EEp9NTmz9w',
    'ip_address'  => '1.2.3.4'
])->send();
```

And get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Omnipay\Pin\Gateway::setApiKey()

Do I need a legit 'card_token'? The one here is from the website's example - I was just hoping it would still process the transaction in the sandbox environment.

Comment: php says to you that `Gateway` class doesn't have a method with name `setApiKey`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A look at [Omnipay's Pin-gateway implementation](https://github.com/adrianmacneil/omnipay/blob/master/src/Omnipay/Pin/Gateway.php) shows that the method is actually called `setSecretKey()` (not `setApiKey()`).

So `$gateway->setSecretKey('key');` should do the trick.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks heaps! I was searching for alternate method names but was looking for something that used "Api", not "key" haha. Thanks again!